# Abbot exercise 2.7.8 part (c)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having some trouble with part (c) of exercise 2.7.8 in Abbot's real analysis book. The problem asks to prove the statement if it's true and give a counterexample if not. The statement is:

> If $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally, then $\sum n^2 a_n$ diverges.

I think the statement is true. I tried to proceed by contraposition. If $\sum n^2 a_n$ converges, then $\lim n^2 a_n = 0$. So the sequence $n^2 a_n$ is bounded, say by $C$. So $|a_n| \leq \frac{C}{n^2}$. The series $\sum \frac{C}{n^2}$ converges, so $\sum a_n$ converges by the comparison test.

I don't think I found a contradiction in doing this. I don't think the comparison test in this case told me anything about absolute convergence, which would contradict the conditional convergence assumption. This leads me to below that the statement "if $\sum n^2 a_n$ diverges, then $\sum a_n$ diverges" is true, but that seems to me to be completely different than what I was aiming to prove.

Answer (score 3):

You did use absolute convergence! $|a_n|\le C/n^2$ for all $n$ automatically implies $\sum_n|a_n|\le\frac{C\pi^2}{6}<\infty$ is absolutely convergent. If $\sum_n a_n$ only conditionally converges, this cannot happen; contradiction. But if you were just told $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent, you couldn't conclude (because it may be absolutely convergent as well).

This could have been restated as: if $\sum_na_n$ does not absolutely converge, then $\sum_n n^2a_n$ diverges.